# Start animation after modal is closed

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, google-swiffy

I have a modal box setup and controlled with a jQuery snippet.  When a page is loaded it displays a basic disclaimer and sets a cookie.

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        if ($.cookie('showDialog') == undefined || $.cookie('showDialog') == null || $.cookie('showDialog') != 'false') {
        $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
            open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); },
            modal: true,
             buttons:{ "OK": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); $.cookie('showDialog', 'false', { expires: 3650 });  } },
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
             width: 1000,
        });
        }    
});
    </script>
```

I also have a swiffy object that runs when the page loads, the problem is that if the disclaimer displays, by the time somebody has clicked close then the swiffy animation has already run its course.  Is there a way to modify my snippet so that it starts the swiffy animation when the user hits close?

Comment: well.. yes, you can :) place the execution of this `swiffy` thing in the `"OK"` callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t know which part of the code is supposed to start the swiffy animation, but you can use the close event from jQuery UI Dialog like this:

```
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
  //...
  close: function( event, ui ) {
      //start swiffy animation
  }
});
```

But since the animation should also start when the disclaimer was already seen you probably also need to call the animation in an else case of the if that checks for the cookie.